# React navigation drawer content props types definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a custom drawer content using [this guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontent):

```js
const DrawerContent = (props) => (
  <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
    <AntDesign
      name="close"
      size={32}
      onPress={() => props.navigation.closeDrawer()}
    />
    <Text>TEST</Text>
    <DrawerItemList {...props} />
  </DrawerContentScrollView>
);
```

It works well, but I would like type checking on the `props` parameter. So I tried:

```js
import { DrawerContentComponentProps } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const DrawerContent = (props: DrawerContentComponentProps) => (
  // Same stuff
);
```

But my IDE is now telling me that `props.navigation.closeDrawer` does not exist, but it does.

What is the correct way to define the `props` type of the `DrawerContent` function?

Comment: The above code works well for me. Please clarify what you mean by "my IDE is now telling me"? What is the exact error message? What line is reported as containing the error? Sounds to me like it is the thing that is *calling* `DrawerContent` that is using incomplete parameters.

Comment: Property 'closeDrawer' does not exist on type 'NavigationHelpers<Record<string, object>, DrawerNavigationEventMap>'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a know issue of react-navigation library: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6790

In order to make the warning disappear waiting the fix, you can use this notation:

```js
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';


<AntDesign
  name="close"
  size={32}
  // @see https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6790
  onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())}
/>
```

Comment: This was the answer `import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';` all this time I was using `from '@react-navigation/drawer'` and didn't work. Thank you very much